# What would be the best way to implement FILESTREAM sql filemanagment with MVC 5?

Tags: c#, sql, model, asp.net-mvc-5, filestream

i am building an MVC 5 project, and would like to implement FILESTREAM to store Files like image or text in BLOB, but use FILESTREAM data to store the path etc...

i have found little to non regarding MVC 5 way of work with FILESTREAM.
I use [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for references.
If i have a table wich i would like to be similar to this :

```
  EmployeeId INT  NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
  Photo VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM  NULL,
  RowGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  NOT NULL  ROWGUIDCOL
  UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWID()
```

How my model should be created?
And are there specifics that need to be taken into account?
I'm still relatively new to MVC with c# so thank you in advance.